# How to do in-place change of display field in combobox

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS ComboBox which is linked to data which is id and name. I have the valueField set to the id and the displayField set to the name. The data is loaded from a `JsonStore`.

What I want to do is to be able to change the name for a given id in place by editing the textfield part of the `combobox`.

I've got this mostly working by listening to the change event. The change event gets called with a newValue set to the new displayField. I can then change that in the database and reload the store. However, when I move the focus off the combobox the change event gets called again with an id. I do not have a reliable way to differentiate between a change of the text and a change of the selection.

Code follows. Many thanks for any help.

```
 var nameCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
     fieldLabel: 'Name',
     name: 'trailName',
     xtype: 'combo',
     store: nameStore,
     valueField: 'id',
     displayField: 'name',
     typeAhead: true,
     mode: 'local',
     triggerAction: 'all',
     emptyText: 'Select the author for this book...',
     //selectOnFocus:true,
     listeners: {
         scope: book,
         'select': function(combo, record, index) {
             this.authorId = combo.getValue();
             saveBook(this);
         },
         'change': function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
             alert('change: field.value [' + field.getValue() + '], newValue [' + newValue + '], oldValue [' + oldValue + '], segmentId [' + this.id + ']');
             if (oldValue == '') {
                 alert('create trail');
                 var authorDto = {
                     name: newValue,
                     bookId: book.id
                 };
                 Ext.Ajax.request({
                     url: '/RestWAR/personal/book.json',
                     method: 'POST',
                     headers: {
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                     },
                     jsonData: authorDto,
                     scope: this,
                     success: function(response, opts) {
                         var responseObject = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                         bookStore.reload();
                         this.authorId = responseObject.authorId;
                         // Difficult to access the combobox so let's save directly.
                         saveTrailSegment(this);
                     }
                 });
             } else {
                 alert('change trail');
                 var authorDto = {
                     name: newValue,
                     bookId: book.id
                 };
                 Ext.Ajax.request({
                     url: '/RestWAR/personal/book/' + oldValue + '.json',
                     method: 'PUT',
                     headers: {
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                     },
                     jsonData: authorDto,
                     scope: [field, oldValue],
                     success: function(response, opts) {
                         this[0].store.on('load',
                             this[0].setValue.createDelegate(this[0], [this[1]]), null, {
                                 single: true
                             }
                         );
                         this[0].store.reload();
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the behaviour that the change event is called when the control looses focus, however, you should be able to to compare `oldValue` with `newValue` to see if the user has actually changed anything.